# Check site is able to call Google Library/API from particular region

Tags: angular, recaptcha

We have integrated google Re-Captcha in our website but when anyone open it from China it is not working.

- Our App is created in Angular Latest version and library we used is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha
- Also, Google's guide to load such things world-wide is also not working (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-use-recaptcha-globally)
- We thought to make AJAX call to any Google API/URL/JS/CSS or other resource to check whether web is able to contact or now, but Google rejects call AJAX call with Cross-Domain reason.

We just wanted to check from web whether our web is able to load google things or not ?

Please share idea/workaround to overcome this issue.